# Excel VBA, paste special

Tags: vba, excel

I have issues with this paste function
i tried a few thing and cant seem to make it work

heres the code :

```
Sub copy()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A19:B19").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

If i take out the `.PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteValues`, it does copy what i want, the cells it copies is a formula, i just want the value, i checked everywhere to correct this, but nothing seems to work, or am i missing something

Thanks

Comment: Are you attempting to take a range that contains formulas and just paste the values somewhere else?

Comment: yes, in sheet1, the values are made via  formula and i just want to paste the values into sheet 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below:

```
Sub copy()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A19:B19").copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you !!, to think i was missing that extra line of code, shame on me

Answer (score 2):

You need to break your line of code in two statements. Currently, you are passing the result of PasteSpecial to Copy, which expects a range.

Try this instead:

```
Sub copy()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A19:B19").Copy 
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you !!, to think i was missing that extra line of code, shame on me

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Sheets(1).Range("A19:B19").Copy
    Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(4, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

The best way to make vba code, based on simple excel functions, is to use the macro recorder. It will give you quite a good sample, that you can optimize later. If you are using the macro recorder, make sure to use it side-by-side with Excel, thus you can see the code generated in real time:

[image]

Comment: Thank you !!, to think i was missing that extra line of code, shame on me